# Converting posteriors to likelihoods by removing prior

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, likelihood, prior, posterior

I have a set of MCMC chains (i.e., unnormalized posteriors) for a parameter I modeled for a sample of objects. I have a model that requires that I condition on the likelihoods of this parameter. My question is, what is the right way to convert from posteriors to likelihoods given that I have a functional form of my prior?

I'm working in python using scipy to define my prior distributions. What I've tried so far,

```
prior = scipy.stats.truncnorm.pdf(mcmc_chain, a, b, loc=loc, scale=scale) 

likelihood = mcmc_chain/prior
```

But the domain of the prior is different than the mcmc chains, which I think doesn't make sense to then try to divide the mcmc chains by the prior. I thought about reweighting the mcmc chain by the prior distribution but 'prior' doesn't sum to 1 so I don't think that will work as weights and I'm also just not sure if that's the correct approach.

Comment: You have an MCMC sample from the posterior. In case you need a sample from the new posterior associated with a flat prior and the same likelihood, the sample should be weighted by the inverse prior. The fact that the prior values do not sum up to one means that you have to renormalise these weights ie divide them by their sum.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm not sure if I'm getting the prior and inverse prior correct but that might be considered off topic here since that might be more of scipy question.

Comment: But may I ask @Xi'an, in the case where the original prior is a uniform prior then does weighting the sample by the inverse prior make sense? And does it need to happen?